# how to close the parent window from an container window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos, safari

I have a scenario, on exit of the webpage I am opening a pop-up window using window.open and in that window I am creating a div container which has x button to close and looks like a popup but not actually a popup . when x button is pressed. Both container window and parent window should be closed.

The following code worked in all browsers but not working in MAC safari. In safari only the container window is getting closed. This code is present in the container window.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="close();" value ="close"/>

function close() {
     window.open('', '_self', ''); 
     window.close();
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `window.opener.close();` did you try this way?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to open the window:

```
function open_window() {
    window.open('demo2.html', '_blank'); 
}
```

And this to close them both. Works in Safari, IE, Firefox and Chrome. Also, the names of the functions do matter for some reason; when I was using just open() and close() as the function names it wouldn't work at all.

```
function close_windows() {
    window.opener.close();
    window.close();
}
```